# Get Console Output History (including Colors)

Tags: c#, c++, console, output, windows-console

Is it possible to somehow get the Console Output (including the Colors) using C# *(P/Invoke, C++/CLI or 'pure' C++ is also fine by me)*?

It would also be important to read the Console output, which has been printed **before my application has started**.

Imagening, that it is *not* possible to fetch such information, could one be able to use UIAutomation or similar to analyse the console window?

---

I would like to have some kind of result like this (though I can do the actual processing and converting myself):

```
// Pseudo-code //

public struct CONSOLE_CHARACTER {
    public uint xOffset;
    public uint yOffset;
    public char Character;
    public ConsoleColor ForegroundColor;
    public ConsoleColor BackgroundColor;
}

// Fetch the previous output including colors
CONSOLE_CHARACTER[] previous_output = Console.ReadCompleteOutput();
```

---

Some Data like this **must** be accessible somehow, as the graphics card has to draw the console window like any other one, and the user32/gdi32-Libraries somehow must acquire this kind of data...

---

**EDIT:** [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923718/get-console-output-history-including-colors#comment51760183_31923718) proided by [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) did help me find the solution

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684969(v=vs.85).aspx ...

Comment: @udit043: Thank you very much Sir for this quick response. I do however have one little problem: The function does not provide some kind of color information....

Comment: [Console Screen Buffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088.aspx). Everything you need.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thank you, Sir. This was exactly the kind of information which I have been looking for :)